# parallization in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have the following independent nested loop in R and I want to parallelize them on 10 cores, I have read many articles about parallelization on R using foreach however, non of them seems to be working or it's working in serial if ever worked !

I need some help here since inside the loop I write the results into .csv file and in the inner loop I use system calls to run other python script, I'm not sure if this contradicts with the parallelization or not

```
for(x in seq(1,dim(trainData)[1],2)){
for(h in 1:end){
 RMSD=system(command,intern = TRUE,ignore.stderr = TRUE)
 write.table(data, file ="read.csv", append = T, quote = F, sep = ",",row.names=F,col.names=F)
```

Comment: If you want to get paralyzed in `R`, try `while(T){i=1}` :)

Answer (score 4):

Having many parallelized threads writing to the same file almost certainly isn't a good idea. Many things can go wrong if two or more are trying to do this at the same time.

I would suggest that you first combine the results from the parallelization step inside R, and then write out the complete file at once, or have each thread write to its own file, and combine the files afterwards.

Using a the System command normally isn't a problem, given that the executed commands don't interfere with each other.

Please provide more information on what parallelization methods have you tried. Why are they not working? Are you using Windows? If not, then doMC works really well:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(10)

foreach(i=1:10, .combine=c) %dopar% { 
    return(i^2)
}
```